# react search filter with select option

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have implemented search filter to my react app, everything worked fine till i made select tag, to change search filter criteria.

```
class BookList extends Component {

state = {
search: '',
selectedValue: 'name',
options: [
  {
    name: 'Name',
    value: 'name',
  },
  {
    name: 'Author',
    value: 'author',
  },
  {
    name: 'ISBN',
    value: 'isbn',
  }
]
}

updateSearch (e) {
this.setState({search: e.target.value});
}

selectedValueHandler (e) {
this.setState({selectedValue: e.target.value});
}

render () {
      if (this.state.selectedValue === 'name') {
        let filteredBooks = this.props.books.filter(book => {
          return book.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.search) !== -1;
        })
      } else if (this.state.selectedValue === 'author') {
        let filteredBooks = this.props.books.filter(book => {
          return book.author.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.search) !== 
      -1;
        })
      } else if (this.state.selectedValue === 'isbn') {
        let filteredBooks = this.props.books.filter(book => {
          return book.isbn.indexOf(this.state.search) !== -1;
        })
      }

return (
  <div>
    <div className='SearchInput'>
      <input type='text'
      value={this.state.search}
      onChange={this.updateSearch.bind(this)} />
      <select
        id="searchSelect"
        name="searchSelect"
        onChange={this.selectedValueHandler.bind(this)} >
        {this.state.options.map(item => (
          <option key={item.value} value={item.value}>
            {item.name}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
    </div>
    <div className='BookList'>
      <ul>
        {filteredBooks.map(book => {
          return <Book key={book.book_id} name={book.name} author={book.author} isbn={book.isbn} />
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
)
}
};

 export default BookList;
```

when i implement this code i am getting error: Line 69:  'filteredBooks' is not defined  no-undef.

Tried to put this.state.selectedValue instead of name but it also doesn't work.

Any ideas how to fix issue?

Comment: You haven't accepted answers to any of your questions (https://stackoverflow.com/users/8562298/d-wasilewski) - make sure to click the empty check mark next to correct answers to help others find answers

Comment: `filteredBooks` is declared with `let`, so isn't visible outside its `{}` block. To access it in the `return` statement, you should put `let filteredBooks` at the top of the `render` method, and only assign to it (not redeclare) in those `if` statements. (You can also avoid the problem by using `var` instead of `let` but even then the above is better practice.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`let` variables are locally scoped to the nearest wrapping curly braces. Define the variable above the if statements.

```
render () {
  let filteredBooks;
  if (this.state.selectedValue === 'name') {
    filteredBooks = this.props.books.filter(book => {
      return book.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.search) !== -1;
    })
   ...
```

Unrelated, here's one way you could shorten your code:

```
const { books } = this.props;
const { search } = this.state;
const filteredBooks = books.filter(book =>
    book[search].toLowerCase().includes(search)
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for help and tips on how to shorten my code. Everything is working right now and new thing is learned ;)